# Unable to create lambda function in hierarchical pymc3 model

Tags: theano, pymc3

I'm trying to create the model shown below with PyMC 3 but can't figure out how to properly map probabilities to the observed data with a lambda function.

```
import numpy as np
import pymc as pm

data = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 2],
                 [0, 1, 2, 2, 2],
                 [2, 2, 1, 1, 0],
                 [1, 1, 2, 0, 1]])
(D, W) = data.shape
V = len(set(data.ravel()))
T = 3
a = np.ones(T)
b = np.ones(V)

with pm.Model() as model:
    theta = [pm.Dirichlet('theta_%s' % i, a, shape=T) for i in range(D)]
    z = [pm.Categorical('z_%i' % i, theta[i], shape=W) for i in range(D)]
    phi = [pm.Dirichlet('phi_%i' % i, b, shape=V) for i in range(T)]
    w = [pm.Categorical('w_%i_%i' % (i, j),
                        p=lambda z=z[i][j], phi_=phi: phi_[z], # Error is here
                        observed=data[i, j])
            for i in range(D) for j in range(W)]
```

The error I get is

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

In the model I'm attempting to build, the elements of `z` indicate which element in `phi` gives the probability of the corresponding observed value in `data` (placed in RV `w`). In other words,

```
P(data[i,j]) <- phi[z[i,j]][data[i,j]]
```

I'm guessing I need to define the probability with a Theano expression or use Theano `as_op` but I don't see how it can be done for this model.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You should specify your categorical `p` values as `Deterministic` objects before passing them on to `w`. Otherwise, the `as_op` implementation would look something like this:

```
@theano.compile.ops.as_op(itypes=[t.lscalar, t.dscalar, t.dscalar],otypes=[t.dvector])
def p(z=z, phi=phi):
    return [phi[z[i,j]] for i in range(D) for j in range(W)]
```

Comment: I fixed the `itypes` list for my model but I still get `'list' object has no attribute 'type'` because `phi` is a list. I could pass an element of `z` (which is also a list) to the `as_op` function but I need `phi` to be a list argument so I can index it on `z`. It seems I would be able to accomplish this using a `Container` or `Index` object but those classes are not present in PyMC 3. Using a `Deterministic` seems like it would have the same issue because I would still need to index the `phi` list with the `z` RV.

Comment: Just curious if this have been solved. I have some similar trouble here...Hope I don't have to switch back to PyMC2

Comment: There is a `Deterministic` in pymc3 now. See the examples folder in the repository, as well as the `as_op` decorator as shown in `disaster_model_arbitrary_deterministic.py`.

Comment: Yeah I see that but the problem is still I am looking forward to pass a list of pymc3 variable of arbitrary size to the `as_op`....`dvector` wouldn't work as they require a "Theano list", but I can't create a "Theano list" of pymc3 variable.

Comment: Manipulating vectors is non-trivial in Theano because it generally requires the use of `scan`, which is not very intuitive.

Comment: @ChrisFonnesbeck: How exactly should one specify the `p` values as `Deterministic`?