# Is PyMC3 useful for creating a latent dirichlet allocation model?

Tags: python, bayesian, lda, pymc, pymc3

I've spent the last several weeks trying to learn PyMC whereby my main task is using it to build an LDA topic model.  I originally tried this example with PyMC2.3 https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104771/latent-dirichlet-allocation-in-pymc but for a very simple model it ran overnight and never even made it to the sampling step.  Thus I've switched to PyMC3.

Is there any fundamental limitations because the random variables are categorical?  Has anyone ever succeeded in creating an LDA model with PyMC3?  I found a partial implementation at [Unable to create lambda function in hierarchical pymc3 model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28756503/unable-to-create-lambda-function-in-hierarchical-pymc3-model/28838717#28838717) but I couldn't get it to work without a Container, and I don't think the original author was able to either.  Does anyone know of any resources I could study in order to figure out how to build this?

Comment: See here for an example that's not quite functional but getting there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31473459/pymc3-how-to-implement-latent-dirichlet-allocation

Comment: https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc3/notebooks/lda-advi-aevb.html <- this might help. Keep in mind that doing categorical sampling may lead to label switching problems. This problem is exaggerated the higher the number of dimensions. Variational Bayes (an approximation) circumvents this problem to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR The implementation given in the link works and the full code with testing on inaugural speech corpus can be seen at: https://github.com/napsternxg/ipython-notebooks/blob/master/PyMC_LDA.ipynb**

I implemented the solution specified in the link you mention using PyMC2 and got it work on Inaugural Speech dataset. I am not confident of the correctness of the solution provided at the link you mention but the implementation works and gives some topic distribution. However, getting to interpret that implementation is something more suited for a someone who understands the mathematical definition of LDA better.

Comment: Any implementation for PyMC3?

Comment: @Chris This example is for PyMC3 https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc3/notebooks/lda-advi-aevb.html